# Self closing void tags with Ember Glimmer components

Tags: ember.js, glimmer.js

I am in the process of upgrading an Ember app to the latest version (3.17) and have run into an issue with the new Glimmer components. Not having to specify a tag name is great, but I'm not sure how to handle self closing void elements such as an

```
<img>
```

tag. It's obvious that you can wrap your component in a closing tag element

```
<div><MyComponent @name="test"/></div>
```

but I've not come across any examples which use a self closing tag.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe post an example of your *old* code? Or some real use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an example](https://ember-twiddle.com/24cce2865dbdb01004cf0577edab2371?openFiles=templates.components.my-img%5C.hbs%2C) using an `<img>` tag in a component. Not sure if it is what you're looking for, but you can just use the void element inside the component. You **do** have to self close the component tag when you call it.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back. I'm talking about the wrapper. In the docs' cheat sheet they give the example <ul><ChildComponent/></ul> which is fine, but I'm looking for an example where you use a self closing tag such as an <img> for the wrapper..

Comment: Can you give an example in plain HTML for what you're trying to do? Not sure I get what a wrapper means in this case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. Given that the new components are tagless when I saw the docs example above for <ul><ChildComponent/></ul>, I wondered if we were supposed to use the same form for a self closing element so something like <img><SomeComponent></img> but of course that doesn't work and you can put a component directly in the element so I've obviously got the wrong end of the stick on this one - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

you don't. A component renders `html`, and you *can not* put `html` into a self closing tag. A self closing tag has, by definition, no `innerHTML`. What would even expect from a component *inside* an `<img>` tag?

Comment: Sorry - I had the wrong end of the stick here - please see my comments below to @jrjohnson